# No CPP REST SDK in NuGet

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, casablanca, cpprest-sdk

I have never used nuget before in Visual C++ project. But now I got help on `How to use the C Rest SDK NuGet package` [there](https://github.com/Microsoft/cpprestsdk/wiki/How-to-use-the-C---Rest-SDK-NuGet-package).

I have started c++ console project, clicked on `"Manage NuGetPackages for solution...`":

[image]

And got list of packages. Looks like all items are for .NET.

If I type `cpprestsdk` in search box according manual system founds nothing. 
Can I use NuGet for Visual C++ projects and why list is missing. How to install cpp REST SDK ?

UPD:

Yes, by mistake it was C# project, but with C++ project picture is the same.
Console also not helped:

```
Type 'get-help NuGet' to see all available NuGet commands.

PM> Install-Package cpprestsdk -Version 2.9.1.1
Attempting to gather dependency information for package 'cpprestsdk.2.9.1.1' with respect to project 'ConsoleApplication1', targeting 'native,Version=v0.0'
Install-Package : Package 'cpprestsdk,2.9.1.1' is not found in the following primary source(s): 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\'. Please verify all your online package sources are available (OR) package id, version are specified correctly.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package cpprestsdk -Version 2.9.1.1
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand


PM> Install-Package cpprestsdk
Install-Package : Unable to find package 'cpprestsdk'
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package cpprestsdk
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

PM>
```

Maybe something wrong with NuGet sources:[image]

This is how I search for package:[image]

Comment: the screenshot doesn't show a `C++` project, it looks like a `.NET C#` console application ;)

Comment: You should be able to install this package via this command `Install-Package cpprestsdk -Version 2.9.1.1` in the `Package Manager Console`, based on this source: https://www.nuget.org/packages/cpprestsdk/

Comment: I have updated question body with details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I use NuGet for Visual C++ projects?

Yes, you can use NuGet for Visual C++ projects, according to the document: [NuGet for C++](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2013/04/26/nuget-for-c/), NuGet support for C++ projects since from NuGet 2.5.

> why list is missing. How to install cpp REST SDK?

Not sure why your list is missing, I have created a sample to install this package, you can check it:

[image]

Besides, you can also install that package by following the method provided by Matthias in the comment.

If your list is still missing, you can share us a sample how did you install it.

**Update:**

You need to ensure that you can access the network, I noticed that you are using the packages source "`Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages`", this package source is provided by NuGet when you off-line. So when you install packages you need use the packages source "All" or "nuget.org":

[image]

Comment: My list is still missing. I have updated question body with more details

Comment: @vico, Whether your computer has a network? It seems that you are off-line. If not, please use the package sources "All" or "nnuget.org" instead when you install the packages. I have updated my answer, you can refer to the part of UPdate.